# Responsive Media Queries - Where do i put what code?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

This will be my first fully responsive site, so I've looked around and found the basic media queries at the bottom of the post, which seems to match most devices in some way or form.

I started off the code outside of any of these queries (i.e. targeting the average desktop). Then I worked on the first media query for mobile, but the second rule doesn't make sense to me (i.e. everything bigger than 321px).

**It seems to mean everything bigger than 321 up to 768 which is the next rule. I think I'm misunderstanding how this is intended to work?  Can anyone perhaps explain this in a simple enough way? I'm starting to think that all my CSS code should be inside on of these media queries and that I should haven't started with the mobile version first, then expand it gradually as the resolution gets bigger?**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)
{

}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (orientation: landscape)
{

}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)
{

}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)
{

}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) and (orientation: landscape)
{

}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px)
{

}
```

Comment: You seem to understand, the second rule means that any device with a landscape orientation will follow what's inside that media query, then anything below it outside of the query will overwrite it, so the next media query will be used. If you have no code outside media queries, there will be no style applied between 1024px and 1224px as you have a max in your third rule.

Comment: Thanks gaynorvader, I'm correct on saying that even with the orientation rule it must still abide by the screen size rules as well. I.e. landscape + screen size of no more than 321px?

Comment: @Jaques Thaat's correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of media queries is to alter elements so they look good a specific window/screen size.
Mobile First design is beginning to become popular.  Essentially, the developer creates the website to be optimized(looks and acts best) on mobile devices.  Next, he gradually inserts media queries at the end of his css to overwrite the original css.  He does this so that the page adjusts to the user's window/screen size, thus resulting in a better experience.

Here is an example:

```
.ImageGalleryItems {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  background-color: black;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Now, whenever the user's screen size is larger than 768px, the image items will float left rather than display next to each other.  Also, the background color will change.

This is the principle you can use.  If you develop for mobile first, don't add `:hover` effects in your original css because those are not employed for mobile devices.  Then, use media queries to add in those effects for desktop.  This saves data usage and creates cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks Derek, good point about the hover state. I get the basic rules, but I think what's confusing is how to know what screen sizes to cater for. 321px seems to be a common portrait size for iPhone4, but do you then add another rule for Samsung s3 and another for Samsung Note 2? Or, are we looking at a range and then relying on fluid grids to do the rest? I.e. 321px could have a set of rules then group the s3 and the Note2 together?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overdoing it a bit. Reduce the number of Media queries and add some breakpoints where your design "breaks" in some way.

Considering what to put in the queries: one way is writing some form of general CSS, and then overwriting some properties inside media queries. Another way is to simply skip the "alternating" property in your general CSS and setting it inside each of the queries.

So: you do not write ALL your CSS inside media queries. Just the things you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really necessary to put everything in media queries. A media query will only apply to a device and or screen size that falls within that query.

@media 1 doesn't necessarily effect @media 2.

Note: You can also put your media queries in a comma separated list to save time.

This is how I've done it on my site:

```
 /* styles for desktops */
 body{width:100%;}

 img{width:100%;} /* and so on */


@media handheld and (max-width: 960px),

screen and (max-width: 960px),

only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px),

only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px),

only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),

only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)

{
     /*Styles for non desk-tops*/
     /*You Only Need to put styles you want to change in here*/
     img{width:90%;}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about chaining the rules like that.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly just agreeing with what's already been said: you are designing *between* sizes and not for particular sizes.  The most important thing to remember is to lay everything out in percentages and not fixed widths.  The upshot of this is that you should really only need three queries: one for desktop, one for tablet and one for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a few media queries - I'd think about whether or not you really need all of those.

You can approach these from mobile first or desktop first. Makes no difference really.

I'd recommend having a look at what media queries Bootstrap use as their defaults.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 0):

Always use media queries for both desktop and mobile because if you don't the entire css will render onto browsers, take up space and slowing down ur webpage (not much, but can get huge if you had a big webapp). So my advice would be set media queries for desktop and for mobile. So when it loads it loads only the media queries pertaining to the specs and nothing extra or useless.